# cant submit form formik and react-native-elements

Tags: react-native, formik

I didn't do a whole a lot of work on react-native to being with but the formik and react-native-elements is not getting anywhere with my setup. I am not really sure what I am missing exactly. Basically, the form cannot be submitted. I have a reusable button and input components made out of react native elements. The form don't get submitted. Out of curiousity, I also tried RN's default button to submit the form but it also doesn't work. My sandbox is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-fast-zy7ld).

My setup is pretty straight forward as you can see below. Any help would be great on what I am missing exactly:

FormInput.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { Input } from "react-native-elements";

export default class FormInput extends Component {
  render() {
    let { name, ...rest } = this.props;

    return (
      <>
        <View>
          <Input name={name} {...rest} />
        </View>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

FormButton.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button } from "react-native-elements";
export default class FormButton extends Component {

  render() {
    let { title, ...rest } = this.props;
    return (
      <>
        <Button title={title} {...rest} onPress={() => this.props.onPress} />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

App.js:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { Alert, Button, Image, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import FormInput from "./components/forms/FormInput";
import FormButton from "./components/forms/FormButton";
import * as yup from "yup";
import { Formik } from "formik";

class App extends Component {
  handleSubmit = values => {

    console.log("submitted values ", values);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.app}>
        <Formik
          initialValues={{
            name: ""
          }}
          onSubmit={values => {
            this.handleSubmit(values);
          }}
          validationSchema={yup.object().shape({
            name: yup
              .string()
              .min(3)
              .max(25)
              .required()
          })}
        >
          {({
            values,
            handleChange,
            errors,
            setFieldTouched,
            touched,
            isValid,
            handleBlur,
            handleSubmit
          }) => (
            <Fragment>
              <FormInput
                name="name"
                onChangeText={handleChange("name")}
                onBlur={handleBlur("name")}
                autoFocus
              />

              <Button
                onPress={() => handleSubmit}
                title="React Native Button"
              />
              <FormButton
                title="React native elements child button"
                onPress={() => handleSubmit}
              />
            </Fragment>
          )}
        </Formik>
      </View>
    );
  }
} 
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the error if exist? And did you make a method for submit button so that it can pass the value ?

Comment: there is no error at all. I believe formik is supposed to take care of handleSubmit as part of its props

Answer (score 0):

In you App.js you're buttons onPress should be like below:

```
<Button
   onPress={handleSubmit}
   title="React Native Button"
/>

<FormButton
   title="React native elements child button"
   onPress={handleSubmit}
/>
```

Your onPress do not need to be an annonymous function.